# Building C# project using jenkins

Tags: c#, visual-studio, jenkins, debian

First of all, im not sure if there is a specific forum thats more suitable for request about Jenkins, but I figured I just post it here.

So, I have this C# project, it right now requires Visual Studio 2015 to build and I would like to automate builds with Jenkins. This is the first time I'm using Jenkins and I was able to set it all up, it fetches the code from the gitlab repository, but right now there is no build action configured. For "fun" i tried to simply make it use a "windows batchfile" as build file and added `echo test`. Checking the console output it downloads the repository code and then tries to execute the batchfile, result is:

`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory`

This of course makes sense, but I wonder now, is there a way to build a C# project with jenkins on a debian server without resorting to mono or something? I know that people build C++ projects for windows with Jenkins on a linux root, so there has to be some sort of cross compiling possibilities.

If the Visual Studio 2015 is a dealbreaker I can also strap it down to VS13 or even below. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**/EDIT**

Its probably important to say that Mono is **NOT** an option. Im using features like WPF that are not available for Mono.

Comment: So you don't have access to msbuild/csc?

Comment: I guess not, unless there is a version that runs under debian which i highly doubt.

I have a windows server at my disposal but said server however is for private use only and not supposed to be "known" to the public. Can i instruct jenkins to use that server for building but not show anything to the public that this sever was involved in the build process?

Comment: I don't see why not. Are you expecting the public to be configuring this build? What artifacts of that server are you worried will be left behind?

Comment: No, the public should only be able to download the finished builds. I was just a bit worried since after install the entire jenkins was publicliy available until i actually set up the security in the webinterface. I just would like to avoid that someone sees the IP of the other server in a log message or something.

Comment: Unless you are manually putting it there, there should be no artifacts of the build server in the final binaries/files. I've never noticed any in *our* Jenkins builds

Comment: So whats the way to go now? Install jenkins on that windows server and manually grabbing the builds from that server and uploading it to the actual public server? Or can i direct jenkins on my unix server to use the windows server for building?

Comment: Unfortunately I've never gone that far into the build configs to give you a good answer. Sounds like a good question though! My experience is limited to using the builds and setting up new ones, but its all on the same server.

Comment: After a little bit of research it turns out there is a way to have a windows server as a slave for the main jenkins. Right now my problem is even after setting up security etc even an unregistered user can still see the console output....

Comment: While the slave thing would work i cant seem to manage to properly adjust the viewing rights of jenkins. Either people cant even see builds (if I set Read on Jobs to false) or they can see every single detail whatsoever happening for every build on the server if i set "Read" on Jobs to true. I think im goint to apt-get remove jenkins now and try to find a better solution.

Comment: If it is Just the right to execute ask to change the executor of Jenkins. In Windows is the service account by default That you Can change to a most higher account in privilèges.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jenkins' [MSBuild plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin).

[Jenkins.NET](http://jenkinsheaven.blogspot.com/) is a good blog about using Jenkins in a .NET environment. First post is [here](http://jenkinsheaven.blogspot.com/2011/04/welcome.html?_sm_au_=isV4q2jD207ZsWZr).